# How to interpolate values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have two tables. The first contains indicative conditional rates for a specific number of days (column headings)

| Date | 1 day | 7 days | 14 days | 30 days | 90 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11.01.2021 | 4.36 | 4.36 | 4.30 | 4.49 | 4.64 |
| 12.01.2021 | 4.32 | 4.34 | 4.36 | 4.48 | 4.63 |
| 13.01.2021 | 4.25 | 4.32 | 4.34 | 4.43 | 4.60 |
| 14.01.2021 | 4.26 | 4.35 | 4.35 | 4.36 | 4.58 |
| 15.01.2021 | 4.33 | 4.35 | 4.37 | 4.34 | 4.57 |

And the second table in which I need to calculate the real rate for a given number of days

| Date | Days | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12.01.2021 | 21 | ? |
| 13.01.2021 | 74 | ? |
| 15.01.2021 | 40 | ? |

As you can see, conditional rates are given for some days, and real rates for others. Among other things, conditional rates are given for each day, and real rates only in some of them. How can I calculate this rate? I see the use of linear interpolation here, for example - if the real number of days is 21, then the nearest conditional rate is given for 14 days and I need to extrapolate this value several days in future. I read about `=forecast`, but it not do what I need. Is there a function in Excel that will help me do this or do I need to write a VBA script for this?

Comment: I think the answer will depend on if you are able to get interpolated rates, or if you have to accept the lower rates, for instance on 12.01.2021 - 21 days, are you able to get a rate between 4.36 and 4.48 or will you have to take 4.36 for 14 days and then take 4.34 for 7 days?

Comment: @gns100 I need to take the rate between 4.36 and 4.48 which I can find with linear interpolation (your first case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Office 365:

```
=FORECAST.LINEAR(B7,
 INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH(B7,$B$1:$F$1,1)):INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH(B7,$B$1:$F$1,1)+1),
 INDEX($B$1:$F$1,MATCH(B7,$B$1:$F$1,1)):INDEX($B$1:$F$1,MATCH(B7,$B$1:$F$1,1)+1))
```

From [Interpolate with Excel](https://exceloffthegrid.com/interpolate-values-using-the-forecast-function/)

Surprisingly, linear interpolation is quite hard to do in Excel.

This uses Excel Forecast function `=FORECAST(x,known_y's,known_x's)`.

The `=INDEX` and `=MATCH` pick out the relevant two points on `known_y's` and `known_x's`.

This will work on Excel 2007, but `=FORECAST.LINEAR` must be changed to `=FORECAST` (depreciated soon).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it works great. But there was a problem that if the dates in the strings do not match, it need to make links to the arrays differently. Could you try to do the same with my test table, which I added at the end of my topic

Comment: Edit your question, putting the correct number for the ?, cause you don't want a linear interpolation, 21 gives you 4.48 or 4.63.

Comment: "?" this is what I need to find

Comment: And we cannot answer unless you show us the correct answer.

Comment: how you did, that's exactly what I need, I just would like you to do it with a test table in the topic. There needed to correct the links to the values on another sheet, but I myself do not quite understand how best to do this. p.s. i have not the correct answer because i need to find it

Comment: Ok, I made changes to the topic with new data. Please note that the conditional rates are given in order for all days, and the real rates are only for some of them.

Comment: I'll have a look later.  But VBA macro is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

we need to get a ratio of where the days land between the set point and multiply that ratio to the difference between the upper and lower values, then add the lower value to that result.

One step that must take place is changing the headers to the actual number.

In OFFICE 365 we can use LET to simplify the steps:

```
=LET(head,$B$1:$F$1,
         lkp,B7,
         rng,$B$2:$F$4,
         dt,$A$2:$A$4,
         rw,INDEX(rng,MATCH(A7,dt,0),0),
         mtch,MATCH(lkp,head),
         mtchp1,mtch+1,
         fst,INDEX(head,,mtch),
         scd,INDEX(head,,mtchp1),
         fct,(lkp-fst)/(scd-fst),
          vlue1,INDEX(rw,,mtch),
          vlue2,INDEX(rw,,mtchp1),
          (vlue2-vlue1)*fct+vlue1)
```

[image]

without the let:

```
=(INDEX(INDEX($B$2:$F$4,MATCH(A7, $A$2:$A$4,0),0),, MATCH(B7, $B$1:$F$1)+1)- INDEX(INDEX($B$2:$F$4,MATCH(A7, $A$2:$A$4,0),0),, MATCH(B7, $B$1:$F$1)))* ((B7- INDEX($B$1:$F$1,, MATCH(B7, $B$1:$F$1)))/( INDEX($B$1:$F$1,, MATCH(B7, $B$1:$F$1)+1)- INDEX($B$1:$F$1,, MATCH(B7, $B$1:$F$1))))+ INDEX(INDEX($B$2:$F$4,MATCH(A7, $A$2:$A$4,0),0),, MATCH(B7, $B$1:$F$1))
```

As you can see, it becomes very unwieldy and hard to manage.

[image]

---

Another method with the LET is to use FORECAST.LINEAR instead of math to get the answer after getting the start and end x's and y's:

```
=LET(head,$B$1:$F$1,
         lkp,B7,
         rng,$B$2:$F$4,
         dt,$A$2:$A$4,
         rw,INDEX(rng,MATCH(A7,dt,0),0),
         mtch,MATCH(lkp,head),
         mtchp1,mtch+1,
         fst,INDEX(head,,mtch),
         scd,INDEX(head,,mtchp1),
          vlue1,INDEX(rw,,mtch),
          vlue2,INDEX(rw,,mtchp1),
          FORECAST.LINEAR(lkp,CHOOSE({1,2},vlue1,vlue2),CHOOSE({1,2},fst,scd)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, great way. Unfortunately, my version of Excel lacks the `=LET` function. But in any case, could you try to do the same with the new data (I updated the topic), the difference is that the real rates are not given for all days, and this imposes some problems in the links to the values

Comment: My middle equation does not use LET.  just change the references and it will do the lookup on the date.